# How to handle shared files(dlls) in multiple unrelated projects

Tags: git, repository, azure-devops

I am currently tasked with porting our repository from SVN into GIT.
While I am doing that,I was going to try and break some of our mostly unrelated areas.   We will say that we have some projects in ExternalCustomerCommunications that use projects with ABC.cs    and we have InternalUser UI code that also uses that some file and project dlls.     Of course if I left all that code in one repo currently but and in doing so they can share the ABC dll inside the solutions becuase they are all in the same repository.    Due to the size of our repository and the two parts residing in two complete different servers and applications, I thought breaking some parts out might make sense.

My question is, in order to do that, how would one handle the two repositories both wanting the same shared code?  I understand that a subtree might be a solution but I was not sure if that is advisable.   I read may posts on the horrors of subtrees and submodules.

I would think this is a fairly common situation but I did not know of any best practices for handling it.

I also believe that I read that a single solution either could not or should not have two repositories to it.

If it matters, I am using VSTS and their hosted instance of GIT as well as visual studio (and perhaps sourcetree if it lends itself well to the process)

Comment: The common and efficient ways are submodule, subtree and convert to nuget packages (as Marcin mentions).

Comment: I realize that subtrees and submodules are options I was just under the understanding from various articles that you should approach that with caution.    That being said, (And I realize that Marcin may not be able to answer this) but how does one go about handling submodule or subtrees within Visual Studio/VSTS?   Or are you forced to fall back to running command line options at that point?

Comment: I added detail steps to use submodule and subtree separatelt in my answer. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `SubRepo` is the git repo which manage the referenced project (`ABC.cs`), the the `MainRepo` is the git repo you want to add references from the external repo (SubRepo). Below are the ways to achieve by submodule and subtree separately:

#### Option 1: Submodule

To add `SubRepo` as a submodule for the `MainRepo`, you can use below commands:

```
# In the directory of the local MainRepo directory, such as C:\MainRepo
git submodule add <URL for SubRepo>
git commit -m 'add SubRepo as a submodule for the MainRepo'
git push
```

Now all the files of the `SubRepo` are add in the sub-directory `C:\MainRepo\SubRepo`, then you can refer files under the sub-directory, commit and push and changes.

**Note:** If files in `SubRepo` are updated, you can update the submodule in your `MainRepo` correspondingly with below commands:

```
git submodule update --remote
git commit -am 'update submodule'
git push
```

#### Option 2: Subtree

To add `SubRepo` as a subtree for the `MainRepo`, you can add files of a SubRepo's branch into subdirectory of the `Mainrepo`. Commands to add a subtree as below:

```
git subtree add --prefix=subfolder <URL for SubRepo> master
git push
```

Now git add the files of the SubRepo's `master` branch into the subfolder `subfolder` of the `MainRepo`, merge and commit the changes into your `MainRepo`.

**Note:** If files are updated in the `SubRepo`, you can update the subtree of the `MainRepo` with below commands:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=sub <URL for SubRepo> master
git push
```

Comment: I think this thorough but I have not put it to use yet.    Concerning the followup, it seems that sub modules/trees are most worked with using the command line.   From what I see, the VSTS/Visual studio env.  doesn't allow you to work with those very nicely.   Are there any recommendations for the easiest way to handle this.   As the creator I will be ok with the command line but I suspect some of our developers, not being familiar with the GIT command line might give some pushback and want to know of ways to handle thought some kind of GUI or tool when they manipulate the repos.

Comment: Here is the scenario I see being an issue:   Developer checks out a repo with sub module or tree.    They make changes in the solution in files in both the repo as well as the sub repo or tree.    They have to commit it back.    In VS it does not seem it is as easy as just committing the work bec. I see your commands above(espec. with submodules)

Comment: If the developers need to commit changes to the subrepo, they need to add the submodule repo SubRepo for the local repositories in VS2017 update 5 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/12/08/new-git-features-in-vs2017-update-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Your GIT repositories should be as lightweight as possible and build, test, deployment and dependency management should be handled by some config files. The config files format is usually determined by the used framework or automation tool. In JavaScript, for example, you would use `npm` package manager, to list your dependencies and keep them outside the repository. If you want to share code between two repositories, you create the third repository with new `npm package`, and then in other repos you can use `package.json` (`npm` configuration file) to specify the shared code repository to pull code from during dependencies installation.

If you need build, test and deploy cycle for the shared repo as well, you should publish your artifacts to some special repository, that is build for the purpose (I heard good things about [artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/))

I see that you mentioned `ABC.cs` so I infer C# language. There is a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) package manager that you could investigate for the purpose.

There are also solutions, like GIT LFS, for keeping large files, but I have never needed to use it.